# iPhone, how do i make my toolbar the same black opaque as the nav bar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm using... (although I've tried other things)

Before I I tried, it looked like this..

[image]

```
tools = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 44.01)];
//tools.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
//tools.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
//tools.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
tools.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
```

This looks like this....

[image]

How can I match the navigation bar black opaque scheme ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to add a UIToolBar to a black opaque navigation bar as your pictures show, this blog post seems to provide the answer you're looking for:

http://blog.blackwhale.at/tag/uibarstyleblackopaque/

(Mirrored in case the blog goes away: http://miro.ir/xB8fW/blog-blackwhale-at_tag_uibarstyleblackopaque_)

It shows how to make a transparent UIToolBar that you can place on a black opaque UINavigationBar.

Comment: The link you provided is not longer working! Take this instead: http://blog.blackwhale.at/?p=621

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't try to add a toolbar to a navigation bar.  They're not meant to work that way.  Instead, modify the navigation item for your view controller to display the controls you want.